# How did the First Order manage to build a weapon inside of a planet that big?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Planets have important things inside them, and a lot of it. I don't know if that planet has the same things as ours does but if it does have layers, how could people displace tons and tons of lava and rock? I'm not sure how deep it goes but how could they mess with the core of the planet, and build a weapon and storage system that big without destroying the planet?

Did Snoke or some other powerful force user aid with the construstion? It doesn't seem logical to me for them to build this weapon.

Comment: I would imagine that an army of droids and a fleet of ships with tractor beams would make pretty short work of a small planet

Comment: The planet doesn't have a molten core, it has a crystalline structure indicating that it's not geologically active

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Someone on Reddit [did the math](https://www.reddit.com/r/theydidthemath/comments/3zl5ul/self_i_calculated_the_size_and_gravity_for/) and determined Starkiller Base is a planetoid roughly the size of Ceres.

Smaller planetoids like Ceres aren't big enough to have molten cores for long, so it's entirely possible there'd be no lava to deal with. Just don't pick a recently-formed one.

Comment: Of course if the "planet" is the size of a dwarf planet it will not have sufficient escape velocity to retain a significant atmosphere, and if it doesn't have a molten core it will probably not have much of a magnetic field to protect the atmosphere and surface from radiation.  So I guess that artificial gravity generators and/or force fields around the entire planet would be necessary the keep the atmosphere in and radiation out.

Comment: @M.A.Golding Yeah. Plenty of canonical examples of gravity manipulation - no one's floating around in the Falcon in zero G. Atmospheric force fields are shown in hangar bays, but the gravity manipulation might do the trick on its own.

Comment: Very good answer this solves the lava question but what about the rock @ceejayoz?

Comment: @xpert The Empire clearly has no issue handling enormous amounts of material - the Death Star is moon-sized. It's a galaxy-spanning government with trillions of people, thousands (at least) of planets, droid labor, and whatnot.